# I cant able to save the output string as doc

Tags: python

Hi can any one help me to save this string in doc file. Problem is I cant able to save the output string even if I try to save only last string I'm getting not the complete one.

```
 h='Hello everyone Im new to this world' 

def underline(x):
   print "\033[4m"+ x + "\033[0m"

for item in h.split():
if len(item) >= 5:
    print(underline(item))
else:
    print item
```

I want output to be saved in a doc file.

Comment: Doc means into a txt file or ms word document

Comment: word document then only I can get underlined texts in that.

Comment: May be refer here : https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I did that also. No improvement. I'm getting only the last string not the complete iteration

Comment: @pavitra Can you share the code where you are trying to save to word ? Alteast the part of code which is using python-docx?

Comment: @toheedNiaz above code is the one I'm trying as a sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Python-docx:

```
pip intall python-docx
```

and then use below code:

```
from docx import Document
h='Hello everyone Im new to this world'
document = Document()
p = document.add_paragraph('')
for item in h.split():
    if len(item) >= 5:
        p.add_run(" "+item+" ").underline = True
    else:
        p.add_run(" "+item+" ")
document.save("test.docx")
```

Comment: Thank you.... but I'm getting this error 'invalid mode ('wb') or filename: 'B:\test.docx' don't know what it means!!!

Comment: What version of python are you  using, i have just tested this and it works fine with version 3.6.4